# Using extern with two cpp files and a header c++

Tags: c++, global-variables, extern, variable-declaration

I have two cpp files and a header file, in one visual studio 2010 c++ project, and I would like to link a ustring variable that's defined in one of the cpp files to the other through the use of extern.

This is the code I have now

```
\\Tmp.h 
\\Declare tmp_user and tmp_pass
extern ustring tmp_user;
extern ustring tmp_pass;



\\TmpOne.cpp
\\define tmp_user and tmp_pass
#include "Tmp.h"
ustring tmp_user = username;
ustring tmp_pass = password;



\\TmpTwo.cpp
\\use the defined variables
#include "Tmp.h"
login(tmp_user, tmp_pass)
{
    \\some function
}
```

When I execute this I get a linker error in my TmpTwo.cpp file.

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class ustring tmp_user" (?tmp_user@@3Vustring@@A)

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class ustring tmp_pass" (?tmp_pass@@3Vustring@@A)
```

If I define tmp_user and tmp_pass in my TmpTwo.cpp file I just get two separate empty files.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you linking both `TmpOne.obj` and `TmpTwo.obj`?

Comment: They are both in the same project but I'm not sure how I would link them? Don't they link through the Tmp.h file?

Comment: Do you place "#include Tmp.h" in them?

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot to add that I'll edit my original question as well but yes I have #include "Tmp.h" in both of these files.

Comment: On a Unix machine from the command line (or makefile), you'd run `g++ -o program TmpOne.cpp TmpTwo.cpp` (or `g++ -o program TmpOne.o TmpTwo.o` if you compile the source to object first).  You're on Windows, so your compiler name is different, but you need something similar — perhaps: `cl /o program.exe TmpOne.cpp TmpTwo.cpp` etc. (names and options could be wrong). If you're using an IDE, then you need to tell the IDE to use both object files (source files) to link the program.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and both of these cpp files and the h file are in one larger project which when compiled creates one executable file. Doesn't this do what you are suggesting?

Comment: Dunno — I've never used VS 2010 (or any earlier version), so I can't help you.

Comment: From what I've seen VS 2010 does this automatically when the cpp files are in the same project, only if the cpp or h files are in another project do you need to link them in that way. Which brings me back to my original problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here.  First, this can't really be the code you're using.  Comments start with `//` not `\\` for example.  But assuming that it's otherwise close the problem is that you've declared that `username` and `password` exist, but you haven't actually instantiated them anywhere.

One of your `cpp` files needs to include something like this:

```
ustring username;
ustring password;
```

Comment: Yeah this isn't my actual code its just to show the issue I'm having. If I remove the extern variables everything builds fine. The username and password are also defined variables I just didn't want to clutter the post with too much information.